# How to increase vlc caching beyond 60000 ms?

Tags: vlc

In VLC you can increase cache of online streaming to a limit of 60000 ms. How to make it 5 mins. 
I know this means that the live stream will be late for 5 min. But I want a stable streaming with low internet connection.

Also Is there any other apps that can do this for m3u files ?

OS: windows 10

Comment: Hello! This is a Q&A site for programming related problems. You can view the topics that fall within the scope of SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

VLC cannot cache beyond 60000 ms. This is a technical limitation which we don't intend to change.